# How to price a Loan&borrowing deal(LNB) using cross currency basis?

Tags: swaps, cross-currency-basis

I want to know how we can price a loan&borrowing(LNB) deal in USD using cross currency basis of my domestic currency is euro.
For example, my domestic currency is Euro, I want to buy a LNB deal in USD. So I can convert my EUR to USD using cross currency swap and then buy the LNB deal, so I have a basis risk and interest rate risk on the two deals. But what if I want to see both the basis risk and int rate risk on the LNB deal and I want to price the LNB using cross currency basis
Thanks

Comment: I’m not 100% sure what your question is. You can discount an USD Loan with the USD interest plus the USD/EUR cross-currency basis spread. That would reflect the fact that you do not have USD funding, but instead turn your EUR funding per cross-currency swap into USD.

Comment: Yes this is the ans I was looking for, thank you